# Failed to create BuildServiceHost object. User DOMAIN\MyUsername needs the 'ManageBuildResources' permission

Tags: tfs

I am trying to setup Team Foundation Server Build Automation in my local desktop. I am giving my credentials the service to be run as and my credentials has Admin privileges for the Team Collection as per the IT team. But I am getting the below error

> [ Verify that the running account has the required Team Foundation
>   Server permissions ] Failed to create BuildServiceHost object. User
>   DOMAIN\MyUsername needs the 'ManageBuildResources' permission.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems you provided your personal domain account in **Build Service Properties** window as the Build Service account.

Just as the error info mentioned, please double check the account's permission in your Team Project Collection level, ensure it has the **Manage build resource permission**. You could ask your TFS admin using `tf permission` command to list all related info.

Moreover the Build Service account usually add in `[CollectionName]\Project Collection Build Service Account` group. If you haven't join this group, then add your account.